# JQuery DataTables Multi-Checkboxes in a row issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatable

I am using data table in which row might have checkbox in first column to select row and couple more checkboxes in other columns for associated data.

Problem is when I am selecting row it select all checkboxes within that row. I was wondering how I could fix this issue.

Thanks for help!

There is DataTables select options:

```
columnDefs: [
            {
                orderable: false,
                targets: ['no-sort'],
            },
            {
                orderable: false,
                className: 'select-checkbox',
                targets:   0
            }
        ],
        select: {
            style: 'os',
            selector: 'td.select-checkbox'
        },
```

Comment: That code snippet should work correctly.  Post the rest of your JS code for Datatables and checkboxes.